# Add style to all elements that has a primefaces tooltip

Tags: javascript, css, primefaces, jsf-2

I have a tricky question that I cannot wrap my head around:

My web application is using jsf/primefaces for most of its content, and there are lots of information available to the user only via the primefaces
 - tag. 
Ie:

```
<h:outputText id=myText" value="someValue" />
<p:toolTip for="myText">Some describing content</p:toolTip>
```

Markup would be generated like this:

```
<span id="parentForm:myText">someValue</span>

<div id="parentForm:j_id_m_5_1_7" class="ui-tooltip ui-widget ui-tooltip-right" style="display: none;">
    <div class="ui-tooltip-arrow">
    </div>

    <div class="ui-tooltip-text ui-shadow ui-corner-all">Some describing content
    </div>
</div>
```

Where `"parentForm"` is a generic parameter not related to the case.

div class=ui-tooltip is the tooltip, while the span is

Since the elements that have attached tooltips are many and diverse, is there a global way I can add some style to all those elements that trigger the tooltip (ie if they are `<span>`s or `<label>`s or `<div>`s in the computed code), so that I could signify the items that had tooltips with some kind of differentiating feature? This is probably a js - issue that would need to know what's similar between elements with a tooltip...

Clarification: I want to style the elements that trigger the tooltips, not the tooltips themselves. In the example above, this would be the `span`, not the `div id=ui-tooltip`.
Not sure how PrimeFaces make their tooltips work...

Comment: Can you share a snippet of the generated markup? It may be possible to use a selector such as [id^="j_idt"] that will match all elements having an id that starts with the string "j_idt"

Answer (score 0):

*I've just ran into the same problem and found the following solution to the problem:*

I've added a single [global tooltip](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/overlay/tooltip/tooltipGlobal.xhtml) into the layout. By default, global tooltips works only for the *clickable elements* `a`, `input` and `button`, but this restriction can be removed with the `globalSelector`-attribute. I used a global selector that selects all elements that have a `data-tooltip`-attribute (I have no idea why this isn't the default).

```
<p:tooltip position="right" globalSelector="[data-tooltip]" />
```

Styling all elements that have a tootip can be achieved in the same way:

```
[data-tooltip] {
    background: #ff00ff;
}
```

Actual tootltips are added with a `data-tooltip`-attribute (after [adding the passthrough-namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27821721/5483217)):

```
<p:outputLabel for="foo" value="Foo" pt:data-tooltip="Bar" />
```

An nice side effect of this is approach is, that the single global `p:tooltip`-element is much less cumbersome then adding individual `p:tooltip`-elements;

Comment: You sir are a steely eyed missile man.  I've spent the past day and half screwing around with the globalSelector attribute and having absolutely zero luck.  This did it, thanks man.